# Automated or shorcut for method access logging

Tags: java, logging, automation, field, shortcut

This may come across as a relatively stupid question, but I'm getting tired of having to hard code statements such as:

```
private void doStuff(){
System.out.println(this.getClass().getName().toString()+ someText);{...};}
```

every time I want to 

 So I decided to implement an external method which writes in the output stream whenever I decide I need something written there such as:.

```
public static void println(Object obj, String s) {
    System.out.println(obj.getClass().getName() + " > " + s);
}
```

So the question is, **Is there a way to automatically set the value of the 's' variable in the method above to always default to *"initialized"* when writing source code (using TAB for code completion e.g. Netbeans)?**

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `varargs` as the second method parameter.  This will also allow you to pass multiple debug statements.

```
public class Logger {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "Test";
        println(test);
        println(test, "This is a test");
    }

    public static void println(Object obj, String...vargs) {
        String defaultValue = "initialized";
        if(vargs.length == 0){
            System.out.println(obj.getClass().getName() + " > " + defaultValue);
        }else{
            for(String x: vargs){
                System.out.println(obj.getClass().getName() + " > " + x);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just overload the method with a default value?

```
public static void println(Object obj) {
    println(obj, "Initalized");
}
public static void println(Object obj, String s) {
    System.out.println(obj.getClass().getName() + " > " + s);
}
```